# Why I am getting absurd values on using maximum integer value?

Tags: java, recursion, integer-overflow

I have a problem statement - given `n`, find the least number of perfect square numbers that sum to n.

Due to some reasons, I was trying out the least efficient brute force approach based on formula -

> perfectSquaresRequired(n) = (perfectSquaresRequired(n-k) + 1)   for all
> k which is perfect square<=n

I wrote a recursive function to implement it in java. Here `numSquares` is the function getting called and `getSteps` is the function that implements the recursion logic.

```
Set<Integer> squares;    
public int numSquares(int n) {
    squares = new HashSet();
    for (int i=1; i*i<=n; i++)
        squares.add(i*i);
    
    return getSteps(n);
}

public int getSteps(int k) {
    if (squares.contains(k))
        return 1;
    int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE, cur;
    for (Integer square : squares) {
        if (square>k)
            break;
        cur = getSteps(k-square) + 1;
        min = Math.min(cur, min);
    }
    return min;
}
```

The problem is I am getting absurd values from this code. However if I use anything other than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in statement `int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE` i.e. any value smaller than 2147483647 (even 2147483646), I am getting correct answer.

I have been learning DSA for only a month now. Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> for (Integer square : squares) {
>     if (square>k)
>         break;
>     ...
> }
> ```

This loop expects the squares to be iterated over from smallest to largest. The problem is that a `HashSet` doesn't have a predictable order. If a large square is encountered early then the loop breaks before considering all of the other smaller squares.

To ensure order you need to use a `SortedSet`. Switching to a `TreeSet` fixes the program:

```
squares = new TreeSet<>();
```

Side note, I strongly suggest you add more [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). When `n` grows there are a *lot* of repeated calls to `getSteps` for the same values. You'll get a substantial speed up if you have `getSteps` cache its return values for each `k` and consult the cache when it's called before it goes into the expensive loop.

Comment: although the question was not related to my using HashSet, I did face this issue due to my faulty approach in another question and fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: You were righ about this, I updated my answer John, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Sparsh beware with my original approach (long conversion), as it will calculate correctly sometimes, but will fail with other values. The real solution is this answers', so please don't hesitate changing the accepted mark, it's the fair thing to do!

Answer (score 3):

### Overflow!

*The error starts happening if the value to compute is `>=17`.*

### *Your result is **`-2147483648`** which is....yep, **Integer.MAX_VALUE+1***
[image]

In the recursive operation number **`t+1`**:

```
 for (Integer square : squares) {
      if (square>k)
           break;
    cur = getSteps(k-square) + 1;
    min = Math.min(cur, min);
 }
return min;
```

`cur` overflows as in the operation number **`t`**,  `min` was returned, with a value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

This makes

```
cur = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 // --> -2147483648
```

From there, `Math.min(cur,min)` has found its final value: `-2147483648`

This only happens once, that's why if you set `Integer.MAX_VALUE-1` as `min`, doesn't fail as **it won't overflow** (*and won't be selected as the minimum value neither*).

---

***Cheap workaround: `long`***

*If you need/wish to maintain that code, this would be a workaround.*

***Nope, just don't do this. As John comments below, this just makes the failure less aparent***

### **[His answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66182292/2148953) was the correct solution from the beginning**

---

---

### *Preserve the insertion order*

The insertion order must be respected when retrieving the `squares`. **That's the key here, as **John** correctly states**. There are two type of sets that honor this:  `LinkedHashSet` and `TreeSet`.

Both are **bad** for this scenario, but specifically `TreeSet` is just **terrible**.

For `TreeSet`, `add`, `contains` and `remove` mean `~O(log(N))`. No joke here, just test it executing `numSquares(99)`. It's a low number, but I noticed the time grew exponentially after certain values (55-60). So 99 is more than enough to confirm this.

I waited for 3 hours (for real) and that thing didn't finish. It makes you believe your computer's processing capacity is lower than a one of those mid 90's [LCD videoconsoles](https://i.gifer.com/77C9.gif).

**This was also correctly pointed out by John's answer.**

---

### *My best try*

After testing, the best performance was the code with a mixed approach that used a `HashSet` and an `ArrayList`. The mechanism can be resumed in:

- Add the elements to the `ArrayList` (*it will respect insertion order*)
- Invoke `HashSet.addAll(ArrayList)`
- `HashSet.contains` is the condition check
- `for (Integer square : ArrayList)` is the loop mechanism

This is the code:

```
 Set<Integer> sqSet;  
 List<Integer> sqArr;
 //...
 public int numSquares(int n)
 {
     sqSet = new HashSet<>((n/10)+2);
     sqArr = new ArrayList<>((n/10)+2);  //avoids grow()

     for (int i=1; i*i<=n; i++)
         sqArr.add(i*i);
    
     sqSet.addAll(sqArr);
     return getSteps(n);
 }

 public int getSteps(int k) 
 {
    if (sqSet.contains(k))
       return 1;
    int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int cur;
    for (Integer square : sqArr) 
    { 
       if (square>k)
         break;
       cur = getSteps(k-square) + 1;
       min = Math.min(cur, min);
     }   
     return min;
  }
```

Comment: Switching to long is a band aid. It doesn't fix the broken loop, just makes failure less apparent.

Comment: Tried to find the best approach to this in the update, thanks @JohnKugelman, the failure was indeed hidden, failed sometimes but gave the correct result at other times.

Comment: "I waited for 3 hours (for real) and that thing didn't finish." As I say in the last paragraph of my answer, the solution is memoization AKA dynamic programming AKA caching. Caching `getSteps`'s results avoids the catastrophic blowup at larger values of `n`. Focusing on O(log n) vs O(1) is a micro-optimization, like using a bucket to bail out a leaky boat. Memoization plugs the hole.

Comment: @JohnKugelman  at this point, I'd like to ask you for your oppinion here... do you think recursion is the proper approach for this kind of operation? I mean, the calculus is made faster by hand than with this code (without the caching). Also, you're sincerely good at metaphores.

Comment: Recursion is probably what I'd have thought of, yeah. Memoization is a really powerful tool -- it can change exponential algorithms into linear ones. That's really something. It's not always applicable. When it is, *boy* is it nice cause of how simple it is to bolt on to a brute force algorithm.

Comment: @JohnKugelman thanks for your time, truly appreciated. It's no joke saying a learn a lot from you. Also, yours should be the accepted answer here, no doubt.

Comment: Thanks to you, too. It's nice that you've continued to think this over and update your answer. I really appreciate people who do that. It makes the site a better resource for future visitors. Cheers.